# Android Studio Opencv Canny detection

Tags: android, opencv, edge-detection

I want to add canny detection for an image when I click to button. I cant take any exception but emilator stops working without starting.

```
buton2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View view) {

        ImageView i = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);

        Bitmap bmp =BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.ab);
        Mat srcMat = new Mat ( bmp.getHeight(), bmp.getWidth(), CvType.CV_8UC3);

        Bitmap myBitmap32 = bmp.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);

        Utils.bitmapToMat(myBitmap32, srcMat);

        Mat gray = new Mat(srcMat.size(), CvType.CV_8UC1);
        Imgproc.cvtColor(srcMat, gray, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2GRAY);
        Mat edge = new Mat();
        Mat dst = new Mat();
        Imgproc.Canny(gray, edge, 80, 90);
        Imgproc.cvtColor(edge, dst, Imgproc.COLOR_GRAY2RGBA,4);
        Bitmap resultBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(dst.cols(), dst.rows(),Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Utils.matToBitmap(dst, resultBitmap);

        i.setImageBitmap(resultBitmap);
    }
});
```

Comment: You're going to need to supply a specific error to get an answer

Comment: Code formatting improved and remove unnecessary spacing

Comment: Please add logcat.

Answer (score 0):

my opencv version 3.0.0  so ı must write      under onCreate method
System.loadLibrary("opencv_java3");

so, solve my problem

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the below line into your onCreate method.

```
OpenCVLoader.initDebug();
```